# jquery pass array key value on .post

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<input name="id" value="id" id="id">
<input name="where[abc]" value="abc">
<input name="where[xyz]" value="xyz">
<input name="something_else" value="i do not want this be included on submit">
<input type="submit" id="go">
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", "#go", function(){
  var data = $('input[name^="where["').serialize();
  $.post("url.php", {id:$('#id').val(), where: data}, function(data){ ... })
});
```

How to pass the dynamic where[key] = value to url.php, so that on url.php:

```
print_r($_POST['where']) will show:

[abc => abc, xyz => xyz]
```

Need $_POST[where] as array or json also happy.

It is currently showing as an string and i need to use parse_str($_POST['where'], $where) which looks like not the best way

Comment: Confusing, maybe you want `{where: $('[name="where[abc]"]').val() }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to do anything with your JS: simply serialise the form as is, and let the PHP script handled the named array keys as intended.

And for your JS, simply serialise the form. [PHP will automatically parse the query string to return an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469063/can-i-put-associative-arrays-in-form-inputs-to-be-processed-in-php) in the `$_POST['where']` object.

```
$(document).on('click', '#go', function(){
  var d = $('input[name^="where"]').serialize();
  $.post('url.php', d, function(data){
    // Data handling
  })
});
```

The code above will provide the following query string

```
where%5Babc%5D=abc&where%5Bxyz%5D=xyz
```

...which is valid, and will be parsed by PHP as an associative array identified with the key `where`.

It is difficult to show how PHP code work, but as attached is a PHPfiddle link for a proof-of-concept example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/npm1-4q5i

```js
$(document).on('click', '#go', function() {
  var d = $('input[name^="where"]').serialize();
  console.log(d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="where[abc]" value="abc">
<input name="where[xyz]" value="xyz">
<input type="submit" id="go">
```

Comment: I do not want to serialize the whole form, I only need to serialize input=where[...]

Comment: You do not have to decode or unserialise anything. The entire `$_POST['where']` is an associative array, you can access the values by using key, e.g. `echo $_POST['where']['abc']` will give you `abc`. If unsure, do a var_dump on the `$_POST` global variable. On my local server I get this: `array(1) { ["where"]=> array(2) { ["abc"]=> string(3) "abc" ["xyz"]=> string(3) "xyz" } }`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way to do that with JQuery.

Here i iterate with each input has `name^="where["` and handled to get string between `where[..]` and each `value`.

Use `.where_values()` instead of `.serialize()`.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#go", function() {
  var data = $('input[name^="where["').where_values();
  console.log(data);
  $.post("url.php", {
    id: $('#id').val(),
    where: data
  }, function(data) {})
});

jQuery.fn.where_values = function() {
  var w = {};
  $(this).each(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr("name").split("[")[1].split("]")[0];
    var v = $(this).val();
    w[n] = v;
  });

  return w;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="id" value="id" id="id">
<input name="where[abc]" value="abc">
<input name="where[xyz]" value="xyz">
<input name="something_else" value="i do not want this be included on submit">
<input type="submit" id="go">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in this case, i will still prefer to use php::parse_str() to work out. I thought in case there will be an easy solution in jquery

Comment: @SIDU Yeh agreed to do with PHP side.