# get variable from php form which is in repeating loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php form in while loop with different id.

```
<?php
while($pet = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         ?>
<form method="post" name="petForm" id="petForm">
            <ul id="listAvatars">
                <li>
                <input type='text' name='pet' id='pet' value='<?=$pet['PetId']?>' />
                <img src="<?=PET_AVATAR.$pet['Avatar']?>" class="listAvatar">
                <span onclick='setPet(<?=$pet['PetId']?>)' id="avatarName"><?=$pet['PetName']?></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
</form>
           <?php
    }
?>
```

I want to get different pet id on click event. I am getting valid pet id on click name, by this function.

```
function setPet(petId){
    alert(petId);
    document.getElementById("petForm").submit();
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['pet'])){
    $petId = $_POST['pet'];
    print_r($petId);
}
```

By submitting this form, I am getting only the first pet's id. What should I do to get appropriate pet id on select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move `<form method="post" name="petForm" id="petForm">` outside the while loop

```
 <form method="post" name="petForm" id="petForm">
      <input type='hidden' name='pet' id='pet' value='' />
      <ul id="listAvatars">
 <?php
    while($pet = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     ?>

            <li>

            <img src="<?=PET_AVATAR.$pet['Avatar']?>" class="listAvatar">
            <span onclick='setPet(<?=$pet['PetId']?>)' id="avatarName"><?=$pet['PetName']?></span>
            </li>

       <?php
    }
 ?>
        </ul>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function setPet(petId){
   alert(petId);
   document.getElementById("pet").value=petId;
   document.getElementById("petForm").submit();
 }
```

Comment: In alert(petId), I am getting different pet id. but, in form submission, I am getting only the last element.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is wrapping over separate `form` fields. When you click submit, it's only going to submit the respective form and not the others.

What you probably want to do is move the `form` fields outside of the loop, so that all **petIds** are passed. As it stands though, you're going to need to update the name to something like `pet[]` so PHP knows it's an array of **petIds**.

See: [Posting array from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152436/posting-array-from-form)

**Edit**

It seems the real question is really:

> When I click a petId, how do I POST that petId to a PHP script through
>   a form (without the use of AJAX).

HTML

```
<div id="pet-id-1" class="petid">Pet 1</div>
<div id="pet-id-2" class="petid">Pet 2</div>
<div id="pet-id-3" class="petid">Pet 3</div>

<form action="" method="post" id="pet_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="pet_id" id="pet_id" value="" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.petid').click(function() {
        var pet_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#pet_id").val(pet_id);
        $("#pet_form").submit();
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jwk2J/

Comment: how to get appropriate values for each variables?

Comment: I tried it with making it array. I am getting all the pet ids. but, How can I identify in php which one is selected?

Comment: So you want to receive all of the petIds, but only care about one? Why not just send that one?

Comment: That's what I need to do. I have list of all the pets. I want to send only one which I will select. So, onclick i need to send that perticular pet id to php.

Comment: Ah, so when you click on a particular pet, you want it to fire (AJAX?) a request of to your PHP?

Comment: onselect I want to just submit form . so, I can get that attribute from $_POST['petId'] in php. I don't want to use ajax here.

Comment: See my edit. I think that's what you need. Note the submission is commented out in the fiddle.