# Adding values into array via input form

Tags: php, arrays

I couldn't find replies to this question that worked for me. I need to add values to the `array` via `input` field. I tried with `SESSION` but it also didn't work. When inspecting array with `print_r` every time array started again with `index [0]` thus overwriting former user input, thus not adding new value to the end. But adding new values into array standard way, by declaring new value works perfectly:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = 5;
$a[] = 'Hello';
```

etc.

Can you give me some hint?

Thanks in advance
Danny

Comment: Something like [array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ?

Comment: or `array_push`..?   [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: or pushing array with key name $a['k_name'] = "value" ?

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6152462/208623

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. First start a session. Then create the array if not exists in session array. Add the value of the `inputName` named field. The second one is checking, is the value is already in the array, and if yes, do not add again.

Later, you can access `$_SESSION['myArray']` on any page.

Do not forget to start the session on every page by `session_start();` where you use it.

```
<?php 
session_start();
//If session array not exists create one
if (empty($_SESSION['myArray'])) {
    $_SESSION['myArray'] = array();
}
if (!empty($_GET['inputName'])) {
    $_SESSION['myArray'][] = $_GET['inputname'];
}

//If want to check is the value of inputName exists, and add only once:
if (!empty($_GET['inputName']) && !in_array($_GET['inputName'], $_SESSOION['myArray'])) {
    $_SESSION['myArray'][] = $_GET['inputname'];
}
?>    
HTML starts here.
```