# Post an "array" on submit form

Tags: php

**My code**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="item"><br>
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="item"><br>
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="item"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

What you see here is a simplefied version of the code I have right now. Others things you can't see at the moment are: there is a function to add more rows (jQuery) and to delete rows (also jQuery). So like name='item(countednumber)'), looks to me somehting not to implement. And I also shouldn't know how I can get all the posted values of item1, item2, item3.... etc.

**Question**
Is there a way of like posting item in sort of array or something? Just how can I get all the values posted of item and get the posted values in a correct order/way?

I hope someone can help me with my "problem", thanks in advance!

Comment: you can get all the post variables using a while loop

Comment: @VermaJr. — Not with PHP with those names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting array from form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152436/posting-array-from-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[]` in the input names:

```
<input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="item">
```

Then `$_POST['item']` will be an array of all the inputs.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the quick answer! I will accept your answer in 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

PHP will create an array of data within `$_GET` or `$_POST` if the name ends in `[]` (or `[someIndex]`).

So:

```
  <input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="item"><br>
  <input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="item"><br>
  <input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="item"><br>
```

and then

```
  $_POST["item"] # will be an array
```