# Codeigniter inserting multiple rows into DB using one query from a form

Tags: forms, codeigniter, sql-insert

- This is the model:

```php
public function saveShifts($data) { 

        $this->db->db_debug = FALSE;
        $error = NULL;
        if (!$this->db->insert('shifts', $data)) {
            $error = $this->db->error();
        }
        return $error; 
}
```

- This is the controller:

```php
public function saveShifts(){

            $data = array (
                'user_id' => $_SESSION['id'],
                'day' => $this->input->post('day'),
                'time' => $this->input->post('time'),
                );

        $this->Shifts_model->saveShifts($data);
}
```

- This is the view:

*I can't post it cause it disappears when I post it.*

So the view contains a form with radio buttons selection for each day of the week. You can choose either morning or evening.

MySql DB structure is: when the keys are `user_id` and `day`

```
+---------+---------+--------+

| day      | time    | user_id|

+---------+---------+--------+

| Sunday  | morning | 1      |

+---------+---------+--------+

| Monday  | evening | 1      |

+---------+---------+--------+
```

Well, I have a problem inserting multiple rows to DB using one query. 
In the view, the form contains radio buttons for each user to choose from for each day.
It is only inserting one row (that last one) every time.

Comment: View code is required to give you a suggestion. But this question may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/6152436/12731030

Comment: I tried this way and it didn't work. I'll try to post again the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should update your view form for supporting values for each day. You should name your radio buttons `day[]` and `time[]`.

Also for inserting multiple rows in one query, you can use CodeIgniter [`insert_bacth`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch) method. By using this method your controller and model will look like below:

- model

```
public function saveShifts($data) { 
    return $this->db->insert_batch('shifts', $data);
}
```

- controller

```
public function saveShifts() {
    $data = array();

    $days = $this->input->post('day[]');
    $times = $this->input->post('time[]');

    foreach ($days as $key => $day) {
        $data []  = array(
            'user_id' => $_SESSION['id'],
            'day'     => $day,
            'time'    => $times[$key],
        );
    }

    $this->Shifts_model->saveShifts($data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I still have a problem. My form contains 7 input tags for each day ( Sunday - Saturday) and I'm using type=radio. So since they all have the same name (day and time) as declared at the controller it reads only one of the days and all 7 of them I mean it adds only one row at the end.

Comment: Did you test renaming inputs as I said in the answer?

Comment: Yes, Thank you it worked. Another question, when I tried to display $data in my view, what is the right syntax for example for $data['username'] wasn't working, maybe $data[I]['username'] with a foreach loop?

Comment: It depends on your data structure which you send to view. for detailed explanation please read [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news).

Comment: Can you please check my view code, cause it inserts only the first row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597620/insert-multiple-rows-into-db-using-one-form

Here I have my view code. Thank you