# Insert multiple rows into DB using one form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter MVC framework, I am trying to insert 14 rows into DB. Also, I have 14 calls for the model in my controller. However somehow, it inserts only Sunday morning. Why is that? 
* The view I posted is just a small part that just repeats itself for each day (Monday-Sunday) and (Morning, Evening).

My DB looks like this:

+---------+---------+--------+

| day      | time    | user_id|

+---------+---------+--------+

| Sunday  | morning | 1      |

+---------+---------+--------+

| Monday  | evening | 1      |

+---------+---------+--------+

Model

```
public function saveFinalShifts($data) {

    $this->db->db_debug = FALSE;
    $error = NULL;
    if (!$this->db->insert_batch('final_shifts', $data)) {
        $error = $this->db->error();
    }
    return $error; 
}
```

controller

```
public function saveFinalShifts(){  

    $data = array();
    $dates = $this->input->post('date');
    $days = $this->input->post('day[]');
    $times = $this->input->post('time[]');
    $worker_names = $this->input->post('worker_name[]');

   if(is_array($dates)){
    foreach ($dates as $key => $date){
        $data[] =  array (
            'date' => $date,
            'day' => $days[$key],
            'time' => $times[$key],
            'worker_name' => $worker_names[$key],
            );
        }
   }
    $this->Shifts_model->saveFinalShifts($data);
```

}

View

```
<div class="warp">    
<?php echo form_open('Shifts/savefinalShifts'); ?>
<table class="manage">
<th>
                <input type="date" name="date[]">
</th>
<td>
                <input type="hidden" value="sunday" name="day[]">
                <input type="hidden" value="norning" name="time[]">
                <?php
                foreach ($sunday_morning as $shift):?>
                <br><label><input class="get_value" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="<?php       echo $shift['fullname'];?>">
                    <?php echo $shift['fullname'];
                    ?></label>
                <?php  endforeach;  ?>
            </td>
<td>
                <input type="hidden" value="monday" name="day[]">
                <input type="hidden" value="morning" name="time[]">
                <?php
                foreach ($monday_morning as $shift):?>
                <br><label><input class="get_value" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="<?php echo $shift['fullname'];?>">
                    <?php echo $shift['fullname'];
                    ?></label>
                <?php  endforeach;  ?>
            </td>
</table>

    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value=”send">
<div>
```

This is the output if I print the $data array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-05-10
            [day] => sunday
            [time] => morning
            [worker_name] => Victoria 
        )

)
```

Comment: $dates = $this->input->post('date'); <--- is that correct? Shouldn't be $dates = $this->input->post('date[]');...?

Comment: how does your array $data output look like? write `echo '<pre>';print_r($data); die;` before you call the model

Comment: you try to insert 14 rows, but the array has only one element... Now you need to work on that $data array to have 14 elements

Comment: But I have 14 elements for each day, or isn't that what you meant?

Comment: yes but you are not calling it, see @Salim's comment and use `$dates = $this->input->post('date[]');`

Comment: Now when we echo it shows the whole 14 array times but it doesn't inserts it to DB.

Comment: does $data match the array/object structure as explained [here in the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#inserting-data)?

Comment: Yes, I'll tell you what, we have inserted a specific date 14 times into $dates[], like this: $dates = [$sunday,$sunday.......] and it works, it inserts the batch array but when I try to  insert the Sunday  in a more neat way: $dates = array_fill(0,13,$sunday); 
It won't insert it to the DB although it is displayed when I echo it.

Comment: but that's kind of another question, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, you are right, do you know if there is a row limit for inserting into DB in PHPMYADMIN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213122/discussion-between-vickel-and-victorias-secret).

Comment: In your array, you place worker_name, but in your db you write user_id. Is that the same datatype?

Answer (score 0):

All input post you're submited is array, but you just pick first element of post data in (`day, time, worker_name`) with `[]` like `$this->input->post('day[]');`.
Try to remove `[]` and in additional, move your calling model `saveFinalShifts()` inside if statement to sure you just calling model when `$dates` is array (or not empty).

```
public function saveFinalShifts(){  
    $data = array();
    $dates = $this->input->post('date');
    $days = $this->input->post('day');
    $times = $this->input->post('time');
    $worker_names = $this->input->post('worker_name');

    if(is_array($dates) && !empty($dates)){  // make sure $dates is array and not empty []
       foreach ($dates as $key => $date){
          $data[] =  array (
            'date' => $date,
            'day' => $days[$key],
            'time' => $times[$key],
            'worker_name' => $worker_names[$key],
          );
       }
       $this->Shifts_model->saveFinalShifts($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the error exists because you are writing the `query` outside `foreach loop` in your `controller function`. I've written the corrected code below, see if this helps you.

```
 if(is_array($dates)){
    foreach ($dates as $key => $date){
        $data =  array (
                    'date' => $date,
                    'day' => $days[$key],
                    'time' => $times[$key],
                    'worker_name' => $worker_names[$key],
                 );

         $this->Shifts_model->saveFinalShifts($data); //Move this line inside foreach loop
        }
   }
```

Comment: OP is trying to create an array $data for batch insert via `$this->db->insert_batch()`, not doing single inserts

Comment: What do you mean by that? We have the batch insert

Comment: @Victoria'sSecret if you move that line inside the loop, you are calling the insert_batch() each time. as long as the loop lasts... your approach in your original question is ok, but I suppose your $data is not built correctly, that's why I asked you to check its print_r() output